# What is the best/easiest solution to have an action executed for a button click?

Tags: java, button, processing

I'm working on Processing to create my own API, with buttons and such. Yet I did the button, and I did everything about testing when your mouse is over the button,... But the thing is, I don't really know how to launch a method for the action of the button.

I saw how the basic Java API is doing -with ActionListener and such- but I just don't like it. I wan't my own code - or at least à code I understand.

So I want a Button that launch a method when it is clicked, I've got a boolean (true when the mouse is hovering it... That works fine).

I found some things about the reflection API, and using method.invoke();, but some people where saying that was slowing down the program or being dangerous for private methods.

I saw something about someone talking about method(); whitch apparently can be used to invoke a method ? I searched for it and didn't found anything more.

So it's more a thought question than a code question, I'm not asking for code, but more, how would you create a Button that anybody could use and that will have a certain action symbolized by a method. And more precisely how to launch that method.

Comment: Learn one of Java's existing GUI frameworks. No need to reinvent a wheel.

Comment: What about keyboard controls? Conceptually, what you're trying to do is implement some kind of [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The other answers and comments are talking about straight Java, but you're using Processing. The approach you take in Processing is going to be a little bit less... engineered than the approach you'd use in Java.

However, to put it shortly: **you're over-thinking it.**

You should first check out the existing Processing GUI libraries available [here](https://processing.org/reference/libraries/). The real answer is to probably use one of them, since all of this work is already done for you.

However, if you really want to create your own gui api, then it comes down to a few things:

- Each component should be able to draw itself.
- You need to hook into the top-level events like `mouseClicked()` or `mouseMoved()`, iterate over your components, and call event functions.
- If you want to pass around a method that the button calls when clicked, then you could simply provide an interface that users of your Button class can implement.

There is absolutely no need to use reflection to accomplish this. Here is a simple example:

```
interface ClickAction {
  public void clicked();
}

class Button {

  float x;
  float y;
  float width;
  float height;
  ClickAction action;

  public Button(float x, float y, float width, float height, ClickAction action) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.action = action;
  }

  void draw() {
    rect(x, y, width, height);
  }

  void click() {
    action.clicked();
  }
}

ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();

void setup() {

  ClickAction action1 = new ClickAction() {
    public void clicked() {
      println("Clicked button one.");
    }
  };

  ClickAction action2 = new ClickAction() {
    public void clicked() {
      println("Clicked button two.");
    }
  };

  buttons.add(new Button(25, 25, 50, 20, action1));
  buttons.add(new Button(50, 60, 20, 40, action2));
}

void mouseClicked() {
  for (Button b : buttons) {
    if (mouseX > b.x && mouseX < b.x+b.width) {
      if (mouseY > b.y && mouseY < b.y+b.height) {
        b.click();
      }
    }
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(0);

  for (Button b : buttons) {
    b.draw();
  }
}
```

This is pretty basic object oriented code, and there is no need to over-complicate things by using reflection instead. Just use objects like they're meant to be used.

Note that this approach is pretty much exactly what Swing uses: `JButton` classes can have `ActionListeners` that get called when the button is clicked.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do, my problems was that I didn't knew it was possible to create a class instance and declare a method at the same time, as you did for action1 and action2...

Comment: @ElzearContelly Those are just anonymous classes. It's exactly like creating a class that implements `ClickAction`, just with fewer lines of code. Java 8 makes this even simpler.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I understand the question for 100% but actually, with an `ActionListener` you can make your custom actions and call any method you need, and with `MouseListener`, as well.

For example:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    private CustomButton customButton;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Testing MyFrame");
        frame.createGUI();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        customButton = new CustomButton("Perform Custom Action");
        add(customButton);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class CustomButton extends JButton {

    public CustomButton(String text) {
        super(text);
        this.addActionListener(new CustomAction());
        this.addMouseListener(new CustomMouseAction());
    }

    private void doSomething() {
        doSomething("Custom Button Clicked!");
    }

    private void doSomething(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    private class CustomAction implements ActionListener {
         @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            doSomething();
        }
    }

    private class CustomMouseAction implements MouseListener {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            doSomething("Mouse clicked on Custom Button");
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
            doSomething("Mouse pressed on Custom Button");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
            doSomething("Mouse released on Custom Button");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
            doSomething("Mouse entered on Custom Button");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
            doSomething("Mouse exited the Custom Button");
        }
    }
}
```

---

P.S. You can also make a custom ActionListener(or multiple ActionListeners) and/or custom MouseListener (or multiple ones) outside the `CustomButton` class, and/or you can also 'assign' (add) them to your custom buttons outside the `CustomButton` class.

P.P.S. But it's another question if you want to know how to make custom event listeners:
http://wiki.bukkit.org/Event_API_Reference

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077333/core-java/mr-happy-object-teaches-custom-events.html